# WebClient DownloadDataAsync blocking

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dns

I need async binary download and used WebClient class. The download is async, but with some exceptions. The DNS resolve seem to work synchronously. If the remote server is not responding, the app is blocking for "...cannot resolve" timeout. Is there a way to make it fully asynchronous with some property or I have to use BackgroundWorker and reorganize the download.

Answer (score 1):

See [System.Net.Dns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns(v=vs.110).aspx) for DNS resolution services which can be executed asynchronously.

You can use the `Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync()` or `Dns.GetHostEntryAsync()` method to asynchronously look up for a given host name the IP addresses or host entry information, respectively. Then you can use the resulting IP address information to directly specify the remote host for your `WebClient` operations, bypassing its DNS resolution delay.

You state in a comment that you are doing the following:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = null;
wc.DownloadDataCompleted +=
    new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadDataCompleted);
wc.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://www.undefined-domain.com"));
```

I recommend that along with using `await` for the DNS lookup, you also use it for your download:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] result = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync("http://" + ipAddress.ToString());
```

(You may have to fiddle with getting the IP address formatted from the DNS result to something appropriate for `WebClient`)

If you need more specific advice than that, I recommend you fix your question so that it's clearer and (very important) includes a good code example showing exactly what you're doing now and explaining how you want it to be different.